# Reversing words in a Python string (including punctuation)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I wrote a program to reverse the words in a given sentence here:

```
def rev_each_word_in(Sentence):

print(' '.join(Word[::-1] for Word in Sentence.split()))
```

As my input for Sentence I used "to be or not to be that is the question." This returns the following:

```
ot eb ro ton ot eb taht si eht .noitseuq
```

It's almost exactly what I want, but is there a way that the period could remain at the end of the sentence, so the return would be:

```
ot eb ro ton ot eb taht si eht noitseuq.
```

Comment: So you want "don't" to become "tno'd"?

Comment: Do you essentially want all punctuation to remain in the same position?

Answer (score 3):

Here comes some ugliness that takes care of this in one line:

```
from string import punctuation as p
print(' '.join(w[::-1] if w[-1] not in p else w[:-1][::-1] + w[-1] for w in Sentence.split()))
```

Where we reverse fully if the last character in a word is not in the punctuation string and if it is we reverse the string up until the punctuation and then add the punctuation to it. prints out:

```
ot eb ro ton ot eb taht si eht noitseuq.
```

Slimming it down as much as I can because I'm ashamed of it:

```
# similar to  [::-1]
r = slice(None, None,-1)
# cut down chars!    
l = Sentence.split()
# reverse condition too and use shorter names
print(' '.join(w[:-1][r] + w[-1] if w[-1] in p else w[r] for w in l))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to pass a function as the `repl` argument to [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), so we can use that to match words and reverse them:

```
import re

def rev_each_word_in(sentence):
    return re.sub(r'\b\S*\b', lambda m: m.group(0)[::-1], sentence)
```

The pattern `\b\S*\b` matches a word boundary, followed by an arbitrary number of non-whitespace characters, followed by a word boundary.

The function (a lambda, for brevity) takes [`group(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group) (the complete text of the match) for each match, and reverses it the usual way using slicing.

Examples:

```
>>> rev_each_word_in('to be or not to be that is the question.')
'ot eb ro ton ot eb taht si eht noitseuq.'
```

```
>>> rev_each_word_in("whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer")
"rehtehw 'sit relbon ni eht dnim ot reffus"
```

```
>>> rev_each_word_in("aye, there's the rub")
"eya, s'ereht eht bur"
```

As you can see, this preserves the position of punctuation immediately before or after words, while maintaining it in the "correct" position inside each reversed word.

Answer (score 1):

Your specifications are still unclear, but if you want only the letters to be reversed within a word, maybe you could try something like

```
def reverse_letters(word):
    lets = (c for c in reversed(word) if c.isalpha())
    return ''.join([c if not c.isalpha() else next(lets)
                    for c in word])

def reverse_sentence(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    return ' '.join([reverse_letters(word) for word in words])
```

which gives me

```
In [23]: reverse_sentence("to be or not to be, that is the question.")
Out[23]: 'ot eb ro ton ot eb, taht si eht noitseuq.'

In [24]: reverse_sentence("Don't try this at home!")
Out[24]: "tno'D yrt siht ta emoh!"
```

Comment: Nice! (at least, if you've interpreted what OP wants correctly ...)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to this:

```
def rev_each_word_in(Sentence):
    if Sentence[-1] == '.':
        Sentence = Sentence[:-1]
        print(' '.join(Word[::-1] for Word in Sentence.split())+".")
    else:
        print(' '.join(Word[::-1] for Word in Sentence.split()))
```

Comment: This only works for a single period at the end of a sentence.

Comment: Correct. That appears to be what the OP wanted.

Comment: maybe more practical a `Sentece.rstrip('.')` to avoid conditional branches

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

def reverse(sentence):
    punctuation = set(string.punctuation)
    words = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        words.append(word.rstrip(string.punctuation)[::-1])
        if word[-1] in punctuation:
           words[-1] = words[-1]+word[-1]
    return ' '.join(words)
```

Output:

```
In [152]: reverse("to be or not to be that is the question.")
Out[152]: 'ot eb ro ton ot eb taht si eht noitseuq.'
```

And this will work for any punctuation in your sentence:

```
In [153]: reverse("to be or not to be; that is the question.")
Out[153]: 'ot eb ro ton ot eb; taht si eht noitseuq.'
```